# Prolog element in lists replacement

Tags: list, replace, prolog

Hi i was wondering if you could help me out with this

From programming in Prolog:  write Prolog script for replacement any given element in lists by an another given element. For example:

```
replace( 3, a,[1,2,3,4,3,5], [1,2,a,4,a,5])=true
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: I havent tried anything yet, im not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 15):

In Prolog, most list processing is done by processing the head and then recursively processing the rest of the list. Of course, you can't forget about the base case, which is an empty list.

Replacing anything with anything in an empty list results again in an empty list. If the head of the list is the same as the element to replace, replace it, otherwise, keep it as it is. In both cases, process recursively the rest of the list. Translated from English into Prolog:

```
replace(_, _, [], []).
replace(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- replace(O, R, T, T2).
replace(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= O, replace(O, R, T, T2).
```

Answer (score 10):

*All* implementations presented so far in other answers are *logically unsound* when being used with non-ground terms. Consider the original query and a slight variant:

```
?- replace(3,three,[1,2,3],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,three] ;                 % OK: correct
false

?- A=3, replace(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs).   % OK: correct
Xs = [1,2,B], A = 3 ;
false
```

It works! Let's ask some very similar queries:

```
?- replace(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs).        % FAIL: should succeed more than once...
Xs = [B,2,3], A = 1 ;              %       ... but the other solutions are missing 
false

?- replace(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs), A=3.   % FAIL: this query _should_ succeed ...
false                              %       ... it does not!
```

---

*What's going on?* Put the *blame* on *meta-logical builtins* `(!)/0` and `(\=)/2`, which are *very hard to use right* and often make code brittle, impure, and logically unsound.

*To preserve logical soundness*, **stick to logical purity** and abstain from meta-logical "features" whenever possible! Luckily, most Prolog implementations support `dif/2` as a logical alternative to `(\=)/2`. Let's use it:

```
% code by @svick, modified to use dif/2 instead of (\=)/2
replaceP(_, _, [], []).
replaceP(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
replaceP(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- dif(H,O), replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
```

Let's run above queries again, this time with the improved `replaceP/4`:

```
?- replaceP(3,three,[1,2,3],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,three] ;                 % OK: correct, like before
false

?- replaceP(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs).       % OK: four solutions, not just one
Xs = [B,2,3], A = 1 ;         
Xs = [1,B,3], A = 2 ;
Xs = [1,2,B], A = 3 ;
Xs = [1,2,3], dif(A,1),dif(A,2),dif(A,3) ;
false

?- replaceP(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs), A=3.  % OK (succeeds now)
Xs = [1,2,B], A = 3 ;                 
false
?- A=3, replaceP(A,B,[1,2,3],Xs).  % OK (same as before)
Xs = [1,2,B], A = 3 ;
false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(_, _ , [], []).

replace(X, Y, [ X | Z ], [ Y | ZZ]):- ! , replace( X, Y, Z, ZZ).

replace(X, Y, [ W | Z], [ W | ZZ] :- replace(X, Y, Z, ZZ).
```

Though, one would usually arrange the 3. arg to be the first one. And strictly speaking above does not replace anything in the list, it just anwsers if 4th arg is like the one in the 3rd but with Y' instead of X'.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(E,S,[],[]).
replace(E,S,[E|T1],[S|T2]):-replace(E,S,T1,T2).
replace(E,S,[H|T1],[H|T2]):-E\=H, replace(E,S,T1,T2).
```

the idea is simple, if the elements match, change it, if not, go forward until empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
domains
I=integer*
K=integer*
Z=integer
A=integer
predicates
nondeterm  rep(I,Z,A,K)
clauses
rep([],_,_,[]).
rep([Z|T1],Z,A,[A|T2]):- rep(T1,Z,A,T2).
rep([H|T1],Z,A,[H|T2]) :- rep(T1,Z,A,T2).
goal
rep([1,2,3],2,4,X).
```